# How to manage full change of a recycler-adapter in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to figure out how to manage an adapter and the corresponding recyclerview appropriately.
The situation is the following:
I'm doing search queries on a database, and each time a new search is entered the whole dataset may change. Should I instantiate a new adapter each time? Or should I just remove items (even all items) from the adapter and insert new ones? Or something else?

EDIT: I should explain the situation better.
I'm using Algolia to store some data, which is retrieved in JSON objects.
Then the JSONArray obtained is passed as string to the adapter, which will parse each element in the string and the corresponding data of each element.
Since the searches are issued each time a new character is written (or removed), each time I obtain a new JSON response, it could be similar, the same, or completely different than the previous one.

Comment: you can go with **instantiate a new adapter each time**!

Comment: If you `Data Type` is not changing, you will just have to notify the adapter

Comment: just do list.clear(); list.addAll(items); adapter.notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: where does your data come from? what database? local sqlite db?

Comment: I added more information in the post @pskink

Answer (score 0):

just add new function for update the list

```
public void updateList(List<DataHolder> list){
     displayedList = list;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or you can do ,

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
```

Also, you can try the following to update recycler view

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(newList));
recyclerView.invalidate();
```